# Как заставить react-select перерисовать список options?

Tags: reactjs

Я пишу компонент на два взаимоисключающих мультиселекта( то есть если опция выбрана в одном, в списке другого она исчезает) на основе пакета react-select. Удаляю из списка элементов выбранный и передаю в react-select, но после рендеринга вижу старый список опций. Как заставить react-select обновить список? Чтение документации ничего не дало.

Или может быть подскажите, готовый npm пакет с подобным функционалом. Спасибо.

Comment: Покажите ваш код, так будет понятнее

Comment: вам надо в метод, где вы в стейт записываете выбранный элемент, записывать измененный массив для 2го списка,
покажите код - будет понятнее